# Jupyter Notebook doesn't open from cmd

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have python 3.6 installed, and I want to install jupyter notebook (not with anaconda, just jupyter notebook). I run `pip install notebook`, but when I write `jupyter notebook` in cmd it gives an error. I had done this previously with python 3.9 and it was working, but now I don't understand the problem. Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "main", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 76, in <module>
    from .base.handlers import Template404, RedirectWithParams
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 24, in <module>
    import prometheus_client
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import (
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\gc_collector.py", line 43, in <module>
    GC_COLLECTOR = GCCollector()
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\gc_collector.py", line 14, in init
    registry.register(self)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\registry.py", line 26, in register
    names = self._get_names(collector)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\registry.py", line 66, in _get_names
    for metric in desc_func():
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\gc_collector.py", line 36, in collect
    collected.add_metric([generation], value=stat['collected'])
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\metrics_core.py", line 126, in add_metric
    self.samples.append(Sample(self.name + '_total', dict(zip(self._labelnames, labels)), value, timestamp))
TypeError: new() missing 1 required positional argument: 'exemplar
```

Comment: Did you tried `pip install notebook` or `pip install jupyter`?

Comment: If you had it working with Python 3.9, why did you downgrade all the way to 3.6?

Comment: Also see - https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html#jupyter-fails-to-start

Comment: I used  ```pip install notebook``` as given here [https://jupyter.org/install](https://jupyter.org/install), I need to use TensorFlow 1.5 therefore I have to use python 3.6

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem while trying to run jupyter notebook with **python3.6**. When I **changed it to 3.7** worked just fine. Maybe there is an issue with python3.6 and jupyter's compatibility.